# I can ssh in manually, but not from a script - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: python, bash, ssh

So I'm currently working on a load balancing python script. In this script I will need to update a file on a server. My plan is to have my python script call a bash script.

In that bash script I'd like to ssh into the server, execute an awk command on a file, then logout.

I can currently ssh into this server manually, because I've set up an ssh key (using Google Cloud Platform). But when I try to run a bash script that only executes

```
'ssh username@externalIP'
```

I get the error: Permission denied (publickey)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Running this down would require a whole lotta details not given (and not really on-topic on site focused on programming as opposed to interacting with ssh as a user or sysadmin). Running `ssh -vv username@ip` in conditions where the issue reproduces and combing through the logs would be a place to start. (If everything looks good when reviewing those logs on the client, bumping the debug level on the server side would be a place to continue).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant parts of your script. Also, you should explain how this ssh instance is supposed to authenticate--ie, what key file it's supposed to use, and how you configured it to use that key for this purpose. It'd be helpful to have the `ls -la` output for your .ssh directory and for the key file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) to connect via SSH? You can specify a key, as shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/batok/2352501).

By using this, you can easily set which commands to execute on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked into paramiko last night, but I thought I'd see this idea through. Your gist is great, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: @mcdito13 Good!

Answer (score 1):

Probably your private key is in your home directory and python is spawning the bash process as a limited user, try changing your script to include the private key explicitly, if still doesn't work you will have to copy the key and change its permission

To explicitly add the private key:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private/key user@host
```